# magento site css not working on frontend after move from server to localhost

Tags: magento-1.9

I setup-ed magento site(1.9) from server to localhost. But design is fully disturbed. i checked via View source and css/js file path are correct.
And Admin panel is working fine.

I cleared Magento cache and Browser cache but it is not working.
[Frontend screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9SMF.png) and [Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc5ds.png)
Please anybody can help me.
Thank you

Comment: _“and css/js file path are correct”_ – your console screenshot proves otherwise, it shows two 404s, at least one of which seems to be for some CSS resource …

Comment: Hello, Yes i checked via view source my all css and js file is working fine. I checked by clicking each css/js file.  what other issue may be ? Thank you

Comment: Anyone can look into this

Comment: Sorry, but it is rather impossible to “remote debug” this. You need to investigate what is going wrong - and I suggest you start with fixing all 404 errors the network panel shows. Maybe check your server configuration, whether all required modules (such as mod_rewrite for pretty URLs, if used, etc.) are available and activated.

Comment: Have you updated the core_config data ??

Comment: In Page.xml file many JS are wriiten together. Which is cause of error. Please can you tell me how can i fix it, I think some php/apache setting issue on my local machine.

 <action method="addItem">
     <type>js</type>
     <name>min/f=skin/frontend/rwd/icebox/js/lib/modernizr.custom.min.js,skin/frontend/rwd/icebox/js/lib/selectivizr.js,skin/frontend/rwd/icebox/js/lib/matchMedia.js,skin/frontend/rwd/icebox/js/lib/matchMedia.addListener.js,skin/frontend/rwd/icebox/js/lib/enquire.js,skin/frontend/rwd/icebox/js/app.js,skin/frontend/rwd/icebox/js/lib/imagesloaded.js</name>
    </action>

Comment: @Bilal Yes, in core _config_data table i change base(secure and unsecure) url only.